# convert pg_LSN to wAL postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have configured the streaming replication using the replication slot. I have checked the view `pg_replication_slots` which contain

```
restart_lsn pg_lsn
```

The address (`LSN`) of oldest `WAL` which still might be required by the consumer of this slot and thus won't be automatically removed during checkpoints.

I want to find the minimum `WAL` required by my standby before the master archive the same.

I thought of converting the `LSN` to `WAL` but I am not able to find any command. Please help me with this.

Comment: You can't actually convert the two. An LSN is just another piece of data stored in WAL. To try and convert, you'd have to scan WAL looking for the specific LSN. You should ask a new question that focuses on what you actually want to know. You mentioned something about "minimum WALL required by standby", but it's not very clear what you're actually after.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion of  LSN to WAL file name could be done using [this formula](https://eulerto.blogspot.com/2011/11/understanding-wal-nomenclature.html):

```
(FF000000 * xlog_master + offset_master) - (FF000000 * xlog_replica + offset_replica)
```

On any PostgreSQL instance run following (ideally running the same major version):

PostgreSQL >=10:

```
psql -t -c "select pg_walfile_name('9F81/724931C8');"
```

PostgreSQL < 10:

```
psql -t -c "select pg_xlogfile_name('9F81/724931C8');"
```

will give you a number like:

```
0000000100009F8100000072
```

which assumes that your server is running on Timeline 1 (first 8 digits `00000001`)

You can use `pg_controldata` to find out on which timeline is your server running

```
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_controldata /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/  | grep TimeLine
Latest checkpoint's TimeLineID:       1
Latest checkpoint's PrevTimeLineID:   1
```

Answer (score 0):

concider using [pg_xlogfile_name](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html) - it takes log sequence number and "generates" `WAL` file name to look for.

> pg_xlogfile_name(location pg_lsn) text    Convert transaction log
>   location string to file name

Comment: @VaoTsun: I'm running 1 master server and 2 slave server with replication, therefor, I can't not automatic cleaning archive files. I must manual detect the safest xlog file name to remove from my wal archive. Is this query will get the correct information I want `select min(pg_xlogfile_name(replay_location)) from pg_stat_replication` ? Thanks.

Comment: The `pg_xlogfile_name` function is now called `pg_walfile_name`.

Comment: it used to back in 2016 :)